# How to fetch the content from same tag from GitHub Api using bash

Tags: bash, api, rest, shell, github-api

I want to get the data of **tag_name** from this link

> https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases

but as we have a lot of releases. How can I get a particular **tag_name**

I do

```
LATEST_RELEASE_TAG=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/latest \
                       | jq ".tag_name")
```

to get the latest tag_name but how to fetch the second tag_name?

eg:

```
[   {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/73283356",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/73283356/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/73283356/assets{?name,label}",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/tag/checkstyle-10.3.2",
    "id": 73283356,
    "author": {
      "login": "romani",
      "id": 812984,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgxMjk4NA==",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/812984?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/romani",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "node_id": "RE_kwDOAL65M84EXjcc",
    "tag_name": "checkstyle-10.3.2",
    "target_commitish": "master",
    "name": "",
    "draft": false,
    "prerelease": false,
    "created_at": "2022-07-31T13:38:47Z",
    "published_at": "2022-07-31T13:54:14Z",
    "assets": [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/assets/73245332",
        "id": 73245332,
        "node_id": "RA_kwDOAL65M84EXaKU",
        "name": "checkstyle-10.3.2-all.jar",
        "label": "",
        "uploader": {
          "login": "romani",
          "id": 812984,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgxMjk4NA==",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/812984?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/romani",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "content_type": "application/zip",
        "state": "uploaded",
        "size": 16208747,
        "download_count": 505,
        "created_at": "2022-07-31T13:54:16Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-31T13:55:12Z",
        "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/download/checkstyle-10.3.2/checkstyle-10.3.2-all.jar"
      }
    ],
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/tarball/checkstyle-10.3.2",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/zipball/checkstyle-10.3.2",
    "body": "https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html#Release_10.3.2\r\n\r\nBug fixes:\r\n\r\n  #11736 - MissingJavadocType: Support qualified annotation names\r\n  #11655 - Update google_checks.xml to have the SuppressionCommentFilter and SuppressWarningsHolder modules in the config by default (and by extension, SuppressWarningsFilter)\r\n\r\n<details>\r\n<summary>Other Changes:</summary>\r\n<br>\r\n  Update releasenotes to use GitHub Pages execution\r\n<br />\r\n  Allow SuppressWarningHolder to suppress the violation with NameCheck\r\n<br />\r\n  Pitest: Kill all surviving mutations\r\n<br />\r\n  Pitest: Activate \"ALL\" mutator group\r\n<br />\r\n  Use Shellcheck to resolve violations code in Shell Script\r\n<br />\r\n  pitest: increase mutation coverage for pitest-imports profile to 100% \r\n<br />\r\n  Update GitHub Action for bump-license-year.sh\r\n<br />\r\n  Solve fb-contrib errors\r\n<br />\r\n  Remove pitest mutation checking HTML model\r\n<br />\r\n  automate execution by Github action bump-license-year.sh on first day of month\r\n<br />\r\n  update code base to have javadoc tag to explain noinspection tag content\r\n<br />\r\n  doc: put example of enableExternalDtdLoad to xdoc\r\n<br />\r\n  update doc for SuppressWarningsHolder\r\n<br />\r\n  releasenotes script generated empty commit\r\n<br />\r\n  Include CDG Accelerator Plugin to boost pitest performance\r\n<br />\r\n  Enforce file size on Java inputs\r\n<br />\r\n  Expand XPath IT Regression Testing\r\n<br />\r\n There are semantic problems in the Chinese error message of keyword `design.forExtension` .\r\n<br />\r\n  prepare-settings.sh fails to create settings.xml\r\n<br />\r\n  Use groovy version provided by `apt` in pitest.yml\r\n<br />\r\n  tweet-releasenotes.sh does not check env variables\r\n<br />\r\n  download of m2 cache from sourceforge.io is slow \r\n<br />\r\n  infra: turns off create dependency reduced pom for shade plugin\r\n<br />\r\n  Update Tests to use new 'verifyXxxxxx' method or 'execute' that use inlined config in Input files\r\n<br />\r\n  Specify violation messages in input files.\r\n<br />\r\n  pitest: increase mutation coverage for javadoc profile to 100%\r\n<br />\r\n</details>",
    "reactions": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/73283356/reactions",
      "total_count": 10,
      "+1": 0,
      "-1": 0,
      "laugh": 0,
      "hooray": 6,
      "confused": 0,
      "heart": 2,
      "rocket": 2,
      "eyes": 0
    }   },   {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/70647006",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/70647006/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/70647006/assets{?name,label}",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/tag/checkstyle-10.3.1",
    "id": 70647006,
    "author": {
      "login": "romani",
      "id": 812984,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgxMjk4NA==",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/812984?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/romani",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "node_id": "RE_kwDOAL65M84ENfze",
    "tag_name": "checkstyle-10.3.1",
    "target_commitish": "master",
    "name": "",
    "draft": false,
    "prerelease": false,
    "created_at": "2022-06-27T13:50:30Z",
    "published_at": "2022-06-27T14:07:12Z",
    "assets": [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/assets/69790751",
        "id": 69790751,
        "node_id": "RA_kwDOAL65M84EKOwf",
        "name": "checkstyle-10.3.1-all.jar",
        "label": "",
        "uploader": {
          "login": "romani",
          "id": 812984,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgxMjk4NA==",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/812984?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/romani",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "content_type": "application/zip",
        "state": "uploaded",
        "size": 15396315,
        "download_count": 3577,
        "created_at": "2022-06-27T14:07:13Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-06-27T14:08:06Z",
        "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/download/checkstyle-10.3.1/checkstyle-10.3.1-all.jar"
      }
    ],
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/tarball/checkstyle-10.3.1",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/zipball/checkstyle-10.3.1",
    "body": "https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html#Release_10.3.1",
    "reactions": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/70647006/reactions",
      "total_count": 8,
      "+1": 0,
      "-1": 0,
      "laugh": 0,
      "hooray": 7,
      "confused": 0,
      "heart": 1,
      "rocket": 0,
      "eyes": 0
    }   },
```

This has 2 tag_name and I want to fetch the data of the second tag_name. Now It's like I always want the 2nd number tag_name only.

-> I want to use this tag_name as the previous release so I want the latest tag_name as the latest tag and the 2nd tag "tag_name" as the previous tag. I want to use these in a shell script.

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question, thank you.

Comment: You want to do this specifically in `bash` (or otherwise the shell)? Do you have something like `jq` or are you limited to using bash script (or whatever)? Is your JSON always in the order of the first `tag-name` is always the latest, and the second `tag-name` is always the previous release?

Comment: I do LATEST_RELEASE_TAG=$(curl -s `https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/latest \  | jq ".tag_name")`
to get the latest tag_name but I don't know how to do it for the 2nd one

Comment: @wkl Yes, I can use any bash. I can use jq. I use jq to fetch the latest tag_name. My JSON is always in order and the second tag-name will always be the previous tag_name only.

Comment: @wkl what If I want to use any of the previous releases with .tag_name and not just the previous release?

Comment: Do you mean any arbitrary number of releases? Like you want to fetch more than two items?

Comment: I mean that for eg: if I want to fetch only tag_name: checkstyle-10.1 from https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases then how I can do that?

Comment: Okay, I see. I’ll update my post in a little bit when I have access to my computer, and tag you when I have some updates to the answer.

Comment: Please make a new post, I will need both as I work on open source so maybe I will need in the future.

Comment: @RahulKhinchi I added a second segment to my answer that just deals with a single release

Comment: @wkl I only want to call the API and get the tag_name (and to be specific any previous release). I only want the tag_name and not the whole release information. Kindly help me with that.

Comment: @RahulKhinchi I don't fully understand the ask there - if you already know the release, you already have the tag? Or do you mean you'd have the release number, which means you can just use the [Get release API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#get-a-release)?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I want to automate sometime after every release and generate the content. So for generation, I want my shell to call an API and take the release number. I can take the release number from the tag_name of the API link. So I just want the tag_name. Now the link has many tag_name as it has all the release name. My question is how can I get a particular tag_name? I can get the latest or previous or any tag_name with your answer.

Comment: This is how I take the latest release: ```LATEST_RELEASE_TAG=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/latest \
                       | jq ".tag_name")``` but how to call any release with jg from https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fetching the Two Most Recent Release

You can have the Github releases API respond with the two most recent releases, and then use `jq` to access all `.tag_name` fields in the array objects and then read them into separate bash variables, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# You only care about the latest release and previous, so you can
# pass the per_page query parameter
github_rsp="$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases?per_page=2)"

# jq lets you access multiple objects in a list
# using different syntaxes. Here, ".[].tag_name" will just
# access every tag_name field in each object of the response array
# and then we put those into an array that we then join with ";'

# We then read jq's output into two separate shell variables
# using ";' as our separator

IFS=";" read latest previous < <(jq -r '[.[].tag_name] | join(";")' <<< $github_rsp)

echo "  Latest version: $latest"
echo "Previous version: $previous"
```

With this as output

```
❯ ./parse.sh
  Latest version: checkstyle-10.3.2
Previous version: checkstyle-10.3.1
```

Also see the following for even more info about how my script works, if you need explanation beyond my notes:

- [`jq` Object Value Iterator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D)
- [Github REST API - List Releases](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#list-releases)

### Fetching a Single Release

Since you asked about getting any arbitrary release, if you have a tag name, you can use the [Github Release-by-Tag API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#get-a-release-by-tag-name), where you put a specific tag into the releases API URL.

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_release() {
    local repo="$1"
    local tag="$2"
    local release_url="https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/releases/tags/${tag}"
    rsp=$(curl -s -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' "$release_url")
    echo "$rsp"
}

get_release "checkstyle/checkstyle" "checkstyle-10.1" | jq
```

And running this script I get...

```
❯ ./single-release.sh
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/62869604",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/62869604/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/62869604/assets{?name,label}",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/tag/checkstyle-10.1",
  "id": 62869604,
  "author": {
    "login": "romani",
    "id": 812984,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgxMjk4NA==",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/812984?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/romani",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "node_id": "RE_kwDOAL65M84Dv1Bk",
  "tag_name": "checkstyle-10.1",
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "",
  "draft": false,
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2022-03-27T14:51:31Z",
  "published_at": "2022-03-27T15:06:48Z",
  "assets": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/assets/60754101",
      "id": 60754101,
      "node_id": "RA_kwDOAL65M84Dnwi1",
      "name": "checkstyle-10.1-all.jar",
      "label": "",
      "uploader": {
        "login": "romani",
        "id": 812984,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgxMjk4NA==",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/812984?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/romani",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/romani/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "content_type": "application/zip",
      "state": "uploaded",
      "size": 13403044,
      "download_count": 6227,
      "created_at": "2022-03-27T15:06:49Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-03-27T15:07:35Z",
      "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/download/checkstyle-10.1/checkstyle-10.1-all.jar"
    }
  ],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/tarball/checkstyle-10.1",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/zipball/checkstyle-10.1",
  "body": "https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html#Release_10.1",
  "reactions": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/62869604/reactions",
    "total_count": 4,
    "+1": 1,
    "-1": 0,
    "laugh": 0,
    "hooray": 3,
    "confused": 0,
    "heart": 0,
    "rocket": 0,
    "eyes": 0
  }
}
```